# Adding colors in cocos2d for iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am trying to do something like the RGB circle using cocos2d:

[image]

I have movable circles (one for R, other for B and other for G) and I would like to calculate the colors of the intersected circles automatically (without creating something over a specific area with the new color - this is the solution I am using).

Is there a way to add colors automatically?

**What am I doing now?**

Currently I am using a 1x1 blank png (as a texture that) in a `CCSprite` and then I change the `CCSprite`'s color (`sprite.color = ccc3(r, g, b)` for each circle).

**What did I try?**

I have tried to use different blend modes in my sprites using `mySprite.blendFunc = (ccBlendFunc) { GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA };`
 and even added some opacity (both directly in the sprite or in the texture using the mode    `[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888]`) but I can't get the effect I want.

I have tried to find a combination in the [website with several blending modes](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) but I didn't find a combination that worked.

Answer (score 2):

1x1 pixel textures are not recommended. I think older devices won't even display them. Use at least 2x2 or better 4x4. Not sure which is the minimum.

If you intend to have one Sprite per pixel, keep in mind that each sprite is around 400 bytes (depends on cocos2d version). That means filling the entire 320x480 screen with sprite-pixels would consume almost 60 MB of memory!

I don't think you can achieve the same result as in the picture with just blend modes. [You can experiment here](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php). You'd have to write a shader program, or otherwise render each subsection as a filled polygon with the color determined by the base color of each overlapping sprite.

Since you can only apply the blend mode to the whole sprite (in this case a circle) the blend mode might be correct for one intersection, but it will also blend with the background which is not what you want. I'm not 100% sure but I think there's a technical reason why this RGB color addition doesn't work with just blend modes. Maybe someone with a better technical understanding of OpenGL ES rendering can help out.

Comment: Thanks for that info about sprites. However, I am filling my sprite with a texture (sorry if I didn't make it clear), so your comment still applies? Also I already tried blend modes and played with the opacity and I couldn't reach the result I wanted.